# Is it possible to use or negotiate different SSL certificates based on client's browser

Tags: ssl, encryption, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, lets-encrypt

I am using let's encrypt now, and I am planning on using my own CA from now on. The usage is for personal media server and cloud storage.

Now I can install the root CA on the devices I own, but occasionally I get visitors when I share stuff. I provided the certificates to install for the visitors and not all of them do that.

My question is, is it possible to use my rootCA signed certificate if it is installed on client system/browser, or else to fallback and use let's encrypt.

Let's encrypt is good enough, but re-issuing every 3 months and verifiying domains is a pain, especially when there is no wild-card.

Comment: The problem you describe does not really make sense for me: If you use Let's Encrypt as a fallback and you expect clients to need this fallback then you need to update the Let's Encrypt certificate  all the time anyway. In this case, why add complexity by trying to use your own CA  additionally to the Let's Encrypt certificate? And even if you would not use LE certificates: properly managing your own CA infrastructure (with OCSP responder, CRL...)  might be more effort than renewing the Let's Encrypt certificate every few month in an automatic way.

Comment: Not on the same domain. However it may be possible if your server can be configured to serve the same content on two domains (with different DNS names) - one for the self-signed and one for the let's-encrypt. BTW: There are let's encrypt clients available that make everything automatically.

Answer (score 1):

No. The ClientHello message doesn't include any information about recognized CAs.